# how to handle an exception "Invalid file signature" in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am using .txt file instead of using excel file so I should be getting 400 error but I am getting 500 error. I want to catch the exception and send a 400 response code with an appropriate response body.

```
[Route("file/")]
[AuthorizeFunction(AuthFunctions.Schema.Create)]
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(Schema))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Guid fileId)
{
     var result = await _SchemaService.Create(fileId);
     return Created("GetSchema", new { id = result.Id }, result);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to catch specific error

```
[Route("file/")]
[AuthorizeFunction(AuthFunctions.Schema.Create)]
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(Schema))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Guid fileId)
{
     try {
         var result = await _SchemaService.Create(fileId);
         return Created("GetSchema", new { id = result.Id }, result);
     }
     catch (Exception exc){
       if (exc.GetType().FullName == "Your_Exception_Name") 
       {
          // Check your exception name here
       }
   }
}
```

or

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  if(ex.InnerException is ExceptionInstance)// exception instance type you want to check
  {

  }
}
```

Update

You can just use `catch(Exception ex)` for general exception then return `BadRequest()`

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  return BadRequest();
}
```